# using JFrame from c#

Tags: c#, java, jframe, weka, ikvm

I want to show a diagram in a jframe from a c# app. The below code is the same for both the java version i made for testing and the c# version which is my main goal. Java version works quite well and quickly while c# lags and doesn't show anything but a blank jframe. The question is how can i make the same code work properly in c#? What am i missing here?

The cl.graph() from the below code, returns a string and the code that works in java but not in c# is below;

```
JFrame jf = new JFrame("My Diag");
jf.setSize(1100, 700);
jf.getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

TreeVisualizer tv = new TreeVisualizer(null, cl.graph(), new PlaceNode2());
jf.getContentPane().add(tv, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

jf.setVisible(true);
```

A sample cl.graph() string is as follows.

```
digraph J48Tree {
N0 [label="dst_bytes" ]
N0->N1 [label="<= 44"]
N1 [label="src_bytes" ]
N1->N2 [label="<= 0"]
N2 [label="dst_host_same_src_port_rate" ]
N2->N3 [label="<= 0.22"]}
```

Comment: Try `jf.getContentPane().add(tv, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);`  **`jf.pack();`** `jf.setVisible(true);`

Comment: Using that, i got a little jframe at the top left. Maximizing results in a little white space where it originally was with the rest black.

Comment: Apparently `TreeVisualizer` does not return a logical preferred size.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: One would need ikvm, weka.jar, and the text of the `cl.graph()` i have. Otherwise the code is just that + reading from a txt file that has `cl.graph()` text written in it. Is there a way to upload the text somewhere rather than copy, paste?

Comment: *"Is there a way to upload the text somewhere rather than copy, paste?"*  Probably, but I won't be following an external link.

Comment: Put a simplifies cl.graph() string on the question. Tried it in netbeans and its still ok in java. `jf.pack()` does the same on both though.